# c copy file permissions from another file

Tags: c, unix, permissions, chmod

What's the simplest way to copy the unix file permissions of a file and set them to another file? Is there a way to store a file's permissions to a variable and then use that variable to set those permissions to another file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. Use `stat()` and `chmod()` (may need root).

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat st;
stat("/foo/bar.txt", &st);
chmod("/baz/quirk.jpg", st.st_mode);
```